# Micrometer doesn't work on Quartz after Spring Boot 3 migration

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

After migrating on spring boot 3, I changed spring-sleuth to micrometer. After that change traceId or spanId are no longer generated in methods, which are managed by Quartz Jobs.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue recently. Here are the steps to solve it

**Root Cause of the Issue**

- **Quartz Integration:** Micrometer doesn't automatically trace Quartz jobs due to their separate execution context.
- **Spring AOP Limitations:** Automatic tracing via Spring AOP may not apply to Quartz jobs running outside Spring's control.

**Solutions**

1. **Manual Instrumentation**

   Using Tracer:

   ```java
    import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer;

    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
       var span = tracer.nextSpan().name("my-quartz-job").start();
       try (var ignoredSpanInScope = tracer.withSpan(span.start())) {
        // Job logic here
       } finally {
           span.end();
       }
    }
   ```
2. **Using @Observed Annotation**

   ```java
   @Observed(name = "my-quartz-job")
   @Override
   public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
      // Job logic here
   }
   ```
3. **Custom AOP Aspect**

   Create an Aspect to intercept Quartz job execution and create spans:

   ```java
   @Aspect
   @Component
   @AllArgConstructor
   public class QuartzJobTracingAspect {
       private final Tracer tracer;

       @Autowired
       public QuartzJobTracingAspect(Tracer tracer) {
          this.tracer = tracer;
       }

       @Pointcut("execution(* org.quartz.Job.execute(..))")
       public void quartzJobExecution() {}

       @Around("quartzJobExecution()")
       public Object traceQuartzJob(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
          // Create and manage span here
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Micrometer Configuration**

Ensure Micrometer tracing is enabled and configured correctly:

```
  management.metrics.export.trace.enabled=true
```

#### *Optional*: Configure a tracing backend (e.g., Jaeger, Zipkin)

**Additional Considerations**

- Compile-Time Weaving: If using AspectJ for other purposes, consider enabling compile-time weaving for Quartz jobs.
- Alternative Tracing Libraries: Explore libraries like OpenTelemetry for more comprehensive tracing capabilities.

**Troubleshooting**

- Verify Micrometer configuration and tracing backend setup.
- Check for conflicting libraries or configuration issues.
- Use logging or debugging to inspect span creation and propagation.

Answer (score 1):

Right now this is not implemented ([`@Scheduled` is planned](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29883)) but right now, as a workaround, you can add the `@Observerved` annotation (+create an `ObservedAspect` bean) on your methods that Quartz will call or create an `Observation` manually:

- Example with `@Observed`: https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#_using_annotations_with_observed
- Example with `.observe(...)`: https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#_introduction

Comment: Unfortunately the first solution does not work for quartz jobs. They are not managed by Aspect, so it's impossible to intercept it.

Comment: You need to create a bean from the class that contain the method for runtime weaving but if you set-up compile-time weaving I can't really see how Quartz can avoid that.

Comment: Ok, creating compile-time weaving is a bit complex. Quartz Job is not managed by spring, so Spring AOP does not intercept it automatically. I want the span context to wrap the whole job, not just beans that are used within that job.